# c# mvvm listview binding selecteditem goes wrong

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have an C# MVVM application which works fine on Windows 7, but does not work properly on Windows XP.

I have a listview of clients and I can perform operations on the a selected client. The **xaml** looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedClient}" e:GridView.AutoSort="True"
                IsTextSearchEnabled="true" TextSearch.TextPath="Name">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" e:GridView.PropertyName="name"
                               Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Name_Header}" Width="150"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding description}" e:GridView.PropertyName="description"
                               Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Description_Header}" Width="150" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Edit_MenuItem}" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Dezactivate_MenuItem}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ListView>
```

**The code behind:**

```
public IEnumerable<client> Clients
{
    get
    {
        //return from database all the clients
    }
}

private client selectedClient;
public client SelectedClient
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedClient;
    }
    set
    {
        this.selectedClient = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedClient);
        this.EditCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        this.DeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

private DelegateCommand<client> editCommand;
public DelegateCommand<client> EditCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.editCommand == null)
        {
            this.editCommand = new DelegateCommand<client>(
                o =>
                {
                    var operationVM = this.UnityContainer.Resolve<IClientOperationViewModel>();

                        operationVM.Name = this.SelectedClient.name;
                        operationVM.Description = this.SelectedClient.description;
                        operationVM.IsNew = false;

                        bool? dialogResult = this.UIManagerSvc.ShowDialog(operationVM);
                        if (dialogResult == true)
                        {
                            //edit client
                        }
                },
                c =>
                {
                    return this.SelectedClient != null;
                });
        }
        return this.editCommand;
    }
}
```

When I select a client and choose Edit at mouse right click, the operation dialog opens for the selected client. I then close the dialog, select another client and edit. The dialog opens but for the previous client.
This happens all the time on an Windows XP, but never on Windows 7.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
Oana

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the SelectedClient setter, does it get hit? Also, how are you calling the EditCommand? You created a DelegateCommand that receives a client instance but you use the one from the parent ViewModel.

Comment: As I don't have VS installed on Windows XP, I've printed messages into a file:
- when I click a record from list, SET is hit and GET also
- when I do right mouse click and choose the Edit operation, GET is hit (I use the value of the selected record)
- after closing the operation form and click another record, SET is hit and also GET
- when mouse right click to edit record, GET is hit with the value selected and also another GET is hit with previous value!